# How can I implement a "complex" INSERT query that retrieve the values calling other queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I am not so into database and maybe I am saying something trivial.

I am working on MySql and I have to implement a "complex" **INSERT** query.

I mean that I have to do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MarketDetails_CommodityDetails
(market_detail_id, commodity_detail_id) VALUES 
( XXX, YYY)
```

where **XXX** and **YYY** are not simple values but are the results of two **SELECT** queries both returning a single value (**XXX** is return by a SELECT query and **YYY** by another query).

I know that I can perform these queries, store the output in a variable and then call my insert query passing these parameters but I am asking if there is a way to automatically do it into my INSERT query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to use `insert values` ? 
just perform an `insert select`

```
INSERT INTO MarketDetails_CommodityDetails(market_detail_id, commodity_detail_id) 
select * from 
(select --Complex select for XXX)
cross join 
(select --Complex select for YYY)
```

Comment: using a `cross join` sounds a bit scary.. a `UNION ALL` instead would be smarter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Except that an `UNION ALL` doesn't have the same effect at all ... Result will be 2 lines instead of 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

You could also use values if you wanted to. Make sure you use 2 parenthesis instead of just 1 and make also sure to use limit statement even if your query always returns 1 row.

```
INSERT INTO some_final_table (column1, column2) VALUES (
    (SELECT some_column_1 FROM some_middle_table_1 LIMIT 1), 
    (SELECT some_column_2 FROM some_middle_table_2 LIMIT 1)
)
```